# I can not merge 2 serializeArray() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge

I want to merge two arrays that I got from two from by using serializeArray() function. But result empty with no error in console.

```
code:  https://pastebin.com/W8pEjeeM
```

[image: Code in picture]

Thank you!

Comment: remove `var` from `data` inside `fn_active` function

Answer (score 1):

***Try this one***

```html
<doctype htm>
<html>
<head><title>test</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- ==============My html================ -->
 
<form id="form1">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="def" />
   <input type="text" name="address" value="def" />
</form>
 
<form id="form2">
   <input type="text" name="username" value="Sample" />
   <input type="text" name="password" value="password" />
</form>
 
<!-- =================== my js file ======================== -->
<script>
//var data;
$(function(){
    var data = $('#form1').serializeArray();
    data.concat($('#form2').serializeArray());
    console.log(data);
 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```